# What to do with old questions without context?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Recently, I have seen **a lot** of questions that seemed to have no context or shown prior research, **especially** the old questions. Should we close them? Or leave them as-is as they are old? E.g. [At this moment vs At this time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234889/at-this-moment-or-at-this-time); this question shows no effort of looking up the difference.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing among old posts, that there were a lot of "Which is correct, this or this?" questions. It's a good sign of a strong community that they happen so much less now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents: feel free to vote to close if you stumble upon them, but don't go actively hunting for them. Closing a question is most effective *before* it gets an answer; afterwards, it's more of a reminder which questions are acceptable and which aren't. Because the Close Votes review queue is quite large, and has been so for a while, we shouldn't increase the workload too much.

Comment: I don't understand  you what you mean about the reminder thing.

Comment: A reminder for future users who want to post a new question with the same (poor) quality as an older question. Basically, the [broken windows theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).